# The .htaccess file is causing a strange "Maximum number of redirect reached" error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
# Remove php extension
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

This is so that /page.php is rewritten as /page.

The problem is that if I  go to a non-existing URL with a "/" at the end, I am getting error 500, and this is logged:

```
2017-10-12 17:51:07.857 [ERROR] [103.9.XXX.XXX:50468] Maximum number of redirect reached.
```

The server is *actually* Lite Speed http://www.litespeedtech.com/ , but we are getting the same problem with Apache.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes after the first rewire you rewire the result again so `page/` to `page/.php` and than to `page/.php.php` and so on. Just do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# exclude all existing directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# exclude all existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# exclude any request with .php at the end
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.php$ [NC]
# Ignore leading and trailing slashes
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

The explanation is in the comments

Comment: OK thanks! But doesn't [L] mean "last", meaning that it shouldn't continue rewriting...?

Comment: This ist a misconception. It means if you would have a others rewrite rule after this one, that the next ones would be skipped. So in this sense it is the last on of this iteration.

Comment: So, once rewritten, the URL goes through the full rewrite again...?

Comment: Yes, until there was no Rule matching or a rule with [END] was matching or source and the destination are the same

Comment: So... could I have fixed my issue by adding an `[END]` after my last rule? `RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [END]` ?

Comment: Almost if you do `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ /$1.php [END]`, because you want `page.php` and not `page/.php`, but as soon as you need other rules or you have externals redirects, than you most likely have to change it again. The Above solution is more flexible and you don't get in to problems if you have to add or change something in the future. Did you try it yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Which checks if the file exists before rewrite.
And works with `/` at the end.